# Prove that $\operatorname{cl}(\operatorname{epi}(f))\subset\operatorname{epi}(\operatorname{cl}f)$.

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, convex-analysis, semicontinuous-functions

> Let $f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$. $$(\operatorname{cl}f)(x):=\liminf_{x'\to x}f(x')$$ Prove that $\operatorname{cl}(\operatorname{epi}(f))\subset\operatorname{epi}(\operatorname{cl}f)$.

$\forall x,\operatorname{cl}f(x)\leq f(x)$, so $\operatorname{epi}f\subset \operatorname{epi}(\operatorname{cl}f)$. We only need to show that $\operatorname{epi}(\operatorname{cl}f)$ is closed, or equivalently $\operatorname{cl}f$ is lower semicontinuous. But I am stuck here.

Comment: I don't agree that $\liminf_{x'\to x}f(x')\le f(x')$. Take $f(x)=\begin{cases}0&\text{if }x\ne0\\ -1&\text{if }x=0\end{cases}$, then $\liminf_{x'\to x}f(x')=0$ for all $x$.

Comment: @SassatelliGiulio In your case,$ \liminf_{x'\to 0}f(x′)=-1$, because you can take {$x'_n$}={$0,0,$...}

Comment: there are two incompatible definitions of lim inf: $\liminf_{x\to x_0} f(x) = \sup_{r>0} \inf_{x\in B_r(x_0)} f(x)$ and $\liminf_{x\to x_0} f(x) = \sup_{r>0} \inf_{x\in B_r(x_0)\setminus \{x_0\}} f(x)$. I think, the question uses the first, while @SassatelliGiulio uses the second (which is also the one on wikipedia)

Comment: the first one is used for instance in the book of Barbu & Precupanu "Convexity and optimization in Banach spaces"

Comment: It is sufficient to show that the set $A_y=\{x\in\mathbb R\colon y<(\operatorname{cl}f)(x)\}$ is open for every $y\in\mathbb R$. Note that $\inf_{x\in B_r(x_0)}f(x)$ in daw's comment is nondecreasing as $r$ approaches $0$. Then it is easily verified that $x_0\in A_y$ if and only if there is $r>0$ such that such infimum is $>y$, and also that for such $r$ we have $B_r(x_0)\subseteq A_y$.